# How do I make a dataframe from a parent dataframe if a particular entry is present in any of the column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image]I want to make a dataframe "A" from a parent dataframe "B" considering only the rows, where "FALSE" is present in any of the column. Currently I am using the code-

```
A = B[(B == False).any(axis=1)]
```

But it is also providing some rows (not all rows) where there is no "False" in any of the column.

Comment: Could you please show the row that provided when there is no "False"?

Comment: I have added the snap of csv output of the dataframe, hope that will help

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure it doesn't work as intended? Maybe you're not viewing the entire range of columns? Try to post a complete row that does not contain any `False` but gets included in `A`, as plain text, not a picture.

Comment: B[(B == False).any(axis=0)] ?